# Adding an extra column onto a gridview and data

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

I have a grid view which is populated after searching through a database, after this I have some calculations going on within a foreach loop like this

```
foreach(DataRow datarow in ds.Tables[0].Rows){
    resturantPostCodeData = checkpostcode(datarow["PostCode"].ToString().Trim());
    foreach(DataRow dr in resturantPostCodeData.Tables["geo"].Rows){
        rLatitude = Convert.ToDouble(dr["lat"].ToString().Trim());
        rLongitude = Convert.ToDouble(dr["lng"].ToString().Trim());
    }
    distanceResult = distance(myLatitude, myLongitude, rLatitude, rLongitude);
}
```

The value at the bottom of the foreach loop `distanceResult` I want those results to be added onto the end of the gridview in its own column

Any ideas of how to do this?

I'm making a web application in `c#` and `asp.net`

Hope you understand my question

Comment: Please add your gridview markup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the column to the DataTable before binding the GridView:

```
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DistanceResult", System.Type.GetType("System.Double")));

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    ...
    row["DistanceResult"] = distance(...);
}

gvDistance.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
gvDistance.DataBind();
```

And you add the BoundField to the GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDistance" runat="server" ...>
    <Columns>
        ...
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DistanceResult" ... />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Additional to ConnonrsFan reply, you can manually bind that column on RowDataBound, but that will make harder to maintain, i suggest this solution, however i'm not sure if you need to add `dt.AcceptChanges();}` after the row updating data.

Comment: @thepanch - I often add fields this way and I have never had to call `dt.AcceptChanges`.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using these two lines of code similar to the answer given by ConnorsFan

```
ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Distance in miles", typeof(double));
```

later on in the code when assigning a value I used

```
datarow["Distance in miles"] = distanceResult;
```

Thanks for your help anyway people